# how can I take input in lower case? the program is running when input is lower case but displaying error when input is in title/upper case

Tags: python-3.x

```
available_cars = {
'swift': 'Rs. 5.19 lakh',
'creta': 'Rs. 9.99 lakh',
'brezza': 'Rs. 7.34 lakh', 
'i20': 'Rs. 5.60 lakh.', 
'baleno': 'Rs. 5.64 lakh', 
'seltos': 'Rs. 9.89 lakh', 
'nexon': 'Rs. 6.95 lakh', 
'verna': 'Rs. 9.31 lakh'
} 

asked_car = input('Please enter (only name) the desired car:') 
if asked_car.lower() in available_cars.keys(): 
    print(f"The {asked_car.title()} is available and will cost you 
      {available_cars[asked_car]}.") 
else : 
    print(f"Please recheck the name enter!")
```

I want to use user input and display carname(key) and price(value) it is working in lower case input but not accepting input in lower case and printing this

```
Please enter (only name) the desired car:Swift
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Rental_Car.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(f"The {asked_car.title()} is available and will cost you 
{available_cars[asked_car]}.") 
KeyError: 'Swift'

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: You can do it by just adding `.upper()` to the end.    `asked_car = input('Please enter (only name) the desired car:').upper()`

Comment: you are a hero man, the world owes it to people like you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `.lower()` the key of the dict `available_cars[asked_car]` in the f-string.

Replacing this line:

```
 print(f"The {asked_car.title()} is available and will cost you {available_cars[asked_car]}.")
```

with this one:

```
 print(f"The {asked_car.title()} is available and will cost you {available_cars[asked_car.lower()]}.")
```

will fix the issue.

---

Another option, which seems more in line with the title of the question, is to append `.lower()` right after `input()`:

```
asked_car = input('Please enter (only name) the desired car:').lower()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, you are a hero man, the world owes it to people like you

Comment: @ArunavDongre the way to repay debts here is by up-voting and accepting answers ;)